# setting up the person

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "set up" here informally mean "to cause (a person) to be blamed or accused"?

> Newsmax host Grant Stinchfield played a clip of Fisher’s reporting in **setting up** the Trump attorney.
>
> “Jenna, I don’t know what’s going on with Fox News, but they just called Mayor Rudy Giuliani a liar. Your reaction?” he said.
>
> “Well, unfortunately for Kristin Fisher, she doesn’t understand how the legal process works and that was, frankly, embarrassing for her,” Ellis replied.

Source: [Business and Politics](https://www.bizpacreview.com/2020/11/20/trump-attorney-jenna-ellis-shreds-fox-news-reporter-kristin-fishers-embarrassing-take-on-thursdays-presser-998061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set something up is to prepare it for something.  You can set a table up for dinner, or set your friend up with a date.  If your friend is sleeping in the guest room, you could set it (the room) up.  Or you could set them up with some blankets and a pillow.  Or you could simply set them up; the listener knows roughly what you mean.  This usage is close you the one given.

Often "setting (someone) up" is a bad thing.  To say something "is a setup" means it is a 'frame job'.  "setting (someone) up for disaster" is a common usage.  It calls to mind setting up dominoes to knock them down, or targets, etc.  But I think in this case it is more like setting up a joke.  One person is saying something that sets the other person up to say something clever in response.